# Autotransformer vs Inductive Divider

Tags: transformer, impedance, inductance, mutual-inductance, autotransformer

Which is the advantage of using an autotransformer instead of a simple inductive divider?

Comment: Please give specific examples. A quick schematic would really help.

Comment: For what kind of application?

Comment: They're just different names for the same thing aren't they? Though I suppose the inductive divider might not have a common core.

Comment: They are not just different names for the same thing.

Comment: I thought that in an autotransformer there is a core, which is absent in an inductive divider

Comment: @Kinka-Byo Well, inductors have cores too. But with an inductive divider you have two separate inductors so you have two separate cores each with their own flux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An autotransformer and an inductive divider are different animals. There are places where one would work, and not the other. You would use each when it's the right tool for the job.

An autotransformer is wound with both windings on a common core. An inductive divider uses two individual inductors, with no shared flux.

The most significant difference in behaviour is that an autotransformer has a low impedance output, in the ideal case, zero. This means it can be used to step down (or to step up) an AC supply, and the load can draw significant power. Its winding inductances are large, not well specified, and in the ideal case infinite. It's not something you would resonate with capacitors and expect to get reproducible results.

An inductive divider looks like an autotransformer *plus an output impedance of the two inductors in parallel*, just like a resistive divider looks like a lower voltage with an output impedance of the two resistors in parallel.

This means you would rarely use an inductive divider to power a load, its output would sag, just like a resistive divider. It's often found in tuned circuits though, with its well defined inductances the correct values to resonate with capacitors.

Comment: What allows auto transformers to have a low impedance output?

Comment: The fact that they're wound on a common core, which is perhaps the zeroth feature of them!

Comment: I mean, what happens magnetically on the common core to allow them to have a low impedance output?

Comment: @DKNguyen do you mean, 'how does a transformer work?' That's the subject of a different question. Basically the two currents add in antiphase to mostly cancel, the very high (ideally infinite) winding inductance effectively forces this current difference towards zero, which forces the current ratio to be constant, which means if the primary has a low impedance supply, the secondary can support arbitrary current, which means it has a low impedance. I might have glossed over a few steps there, it really is a different question.

Comment: That was sufficient.

Comment: An auto transformer has a single winding with one or more taps. The input and output(s) (line) can use any of them in order to achieve step up or step down, but one end of the winding is common to both input and output (the neutral). If the device has two or more wingdings then it isn't an auto transformer, it's a plain transformer and the inputs and outputs are isolated from each other, the don't share a common connection.

Comment: @PeterJennings An auto  transformer has no isolation between input and output. Although it may be built with several windings, they are all connected. One terminal is common to both input and output, which may or may not be at the end.